# How to redefine CalculatedPrice in Shopware6?

Tags: custom-fields, calculated-field, shopware

I'm trying to write plugin in Shopware6, it must add some custom values (like deposit) to Product line item. So I wrote my class

```
class DepositCalculatedPrice extends CalculatedPrice
{
    /** @var float $deposit */
    protected $deposit;

    public function __construct(
        float $unitPrice,
        float $totalPrice,
        CalculatedTaxCollection $calculatedTaxes,
        CalculatedTaxCollection $calculatedTaxesNoDeposit,
        TaxRuleCollection $taxRules,
        int $quantity = 1,
        ?ReferencePrice $referencePrice = null,
        ?ListPrice $listPrice = null,
        float $deposit = 0,
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $unitPrice,
            $totalPrice,
            $calculatedTaxes,
            $taxRules,
            $quantity,
            $referencePrice,
            $listPrice
        );
        $this->deposit = $deposit;
    }

    public function getDeposit(): float
    {
        return FloatComparator::cast($this->deposit);
    }
}
```

Then I use it in my Calculator and then in my PriceProcessor. All goes well until I try to submit my order, but then Shopware6 checks field definintion classes in `Checkout/Order/Aggregate/OrderLineItem/OrderLineItemDefinition.php`, and it checks Price json field against CalculatedPrice, not DepositCalculatedPrice.
So is there any way to resolve it? Maybe I can use somewhere some descendant of `OrderLineItemDefinition.php`? Or make it not checking field definitions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to follow that document https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to/cart-change-price

I also need to implement custom price applying from an external system, and i exactly did it according to that documentation, so you need to set exactly the price during cart processing, you can do it using your DepositCalculatedPrice value.

Comment: But I don't need to change the price! Well, this I also need, but main thing is to add deposit to my product line item.

Comment: In this case, may best place where you can add that data is line item payload or extensions and after that you need to map cart data to order dat in subscriber which subscribes on `\Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Order\CartConvertedEvent::class` event